# How to extract a SQL database design into Visio in a manageable format?

Tags: sql-server, visio

I have a database diagram that I would like to extract from SQL and manipulate it to create a user-friendly and easier-on-the-eye ERD.  The database contains over 200 tables and I would like to map the tables out to show other how it works to others.

I don't want to reverse engineer as Visio reformats the ERD and no longer looks like the model I have in database designs.

I'm aware that you can right-click and copy-to-clipboard however this captures the model as an image which means I can't manipulate it.

Is there an alternative piece of software out there that I'm not aware of?

Comment: I don't think that there's any tool out there that can read from the SQL Server diagrams themselves. All ERD tools will reverse engineer the schema and will auto arrange the tables. You need to either use the diagrams you have now or prepare new ones in another ERD tool..

Answer (score 2):

I'd check out Embarcadero tools Try [Data Architect](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/er-studio-data-architect).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "free" MySQL workbench if you are using MySQL https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/ to reverse engineer the model from an SQL file then re-organize the model into multiple pages.

Comment: unfortunately I'm not using mysql...thanks for your input though.